# Why orderBy does not work for this linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to order by a datetime field, a list with objects like:

```
    // Order search results (posts to be displayed by created datetime).
   if (implicitSelectedVisualiser.PostsSortOrder == PostsSortOrder.CREATED_DATE_ASC)
      approvedSearchResults.OrderBy(s => s.PostCreatedTime);
   else
      approvedSearchResults.OrderByDescending(s => s.PostCreatedTime);
```

The issues is that nothing gets sorted.

Initial order is:

```
2013-06-28 19:52:08.000
2013-06-28 19:38:30.000
2013-06-28 18:35:37.000
2013-06-29 17:07:22.000
2013-07-01 19:12:44.000
2013-07-01 19:15:29.000
2013-07-01 23:51:11.000
```

After sorting from above (it goes on DESC), it remains **the same** while this works perfectly in SQL.

```
SELECT [PostCreatedTime]
FROM [SearchResults]
Where SearchQuery_Id = 10 or SearchQuery_Id = 7
Order by PostCreatedTime desc

2013-07-01 23:51:11.000
2013-07-01 19:15:29.000
2013-07-01 19:12:44.000
2013-06-29 17:07:22.000
2013-06-28 19:52:08.000
2013-06-28 19:38:30.000
2013-06-28 18:35:37.000
```

I am making any mistake in my linq?

Comment: Are you certain `implicitSelectedVisualizer.PostsSortOrder != PostsSortOrder.CREATED_DATE_ASC`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the `OrderBy` method returns a collection rather than ordering against the given collection. Try changing it to the following:

```
var orderedList = approvedSearchResults.OrderBy(s => s.PostCreatedTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

It isnt an inline sort - you need to assign the sorted version to a variable

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
approvedSearchResults = approvedSearchResults.OrderBy(s => s.PostCreatedTime);
```

OrderBy returns an ordered collection , but does not order against the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store your search results somewhere - at the moment

```
approvedSearchResults.OrderByDescending(s => s.PostCreatedTime);
```

Won't be stored anywhere.